# hibernate version 4 jar, maven dependency not in repository - well it is in repository, but my repository is wrong

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Hibernate-core jar version 4.0.0.Final version is **not** available [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core).
My pom shows this :

```
<id>central</id>
<name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
<url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
```

Which provides a link to [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C4.0.0.Final%7Cjar) where the jar **IS** available ... so I expected my maven build to download dependency, it doesn't.

However if I change to CR7 (which is available on first repository) it does work, suggesting to me that my build actually uses the first link as repository, even though the url "resolves" to the second ... ?

What should my repository definition look like to enable me to get the final version of hibernate release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate suggests](http://www.hibernate.org/downloads) using the JBoss Maven repository.  I would therefore use a repository defined thusly:

```
<repository>
  <id>Hibernate</id>
  <name>JBoss Hibernate repository</name>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

...and any other repository coordinate element you wish to specify.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the Hibernate dependency element from your POM?

Answer (score 0):

the repository required was this:

```
<repository>
<id>Hibernate</id>
<name>JBoss Hibernate repository</name>
<url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  Be cautious of using non-public Maven repositories.  JBoss _could_ pull the rug from under your feet!  JBoss' own URL recommendation -- which is what I suggested -- worked without error for me.